# I'm getting wrong output and also I need a simplified solution

Tags: java

I came across a problem. The code is:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int time = input.nextInt();
        int line = input.nextInt();
        input.nextline();
        int[][] PrimaryArray = new int[12][11];
        int[] Number = new int[12];
        boolean[] dualPass = new boolean[12];
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            dualPass[i] = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
            int SourceNode = input.nextInt();
            int DistNode = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            if (SourceNode == 1) {
                    PrimaryArray[SourceNode][Number[1]] = DistNode;
                    Number[1]++;
            }
            if (SourceNode == 2) {
                for (int j = 0; j < PrimaryArray[DistNode].length; j++) {
                    if (PrimaryArray[DistNode][j] == SourceNode)
                        dualPass[2] = true;
                }
                if (dualPass[2] != true) {
                    PrimaryArray[SourceNode][Number[2]] = DistNode;
                    Number[2]++;
                }
                dualPass[2] = false;
            }
            if (SourceNode == 3) {
                for (int j = 0; j < PrimaryArray[DistNode].length; j++) {
                    if (PrimaryArray[DistNode][j] == SourceNode)
                        dualPass[3] = true;
                }
                if (dualPass[3] != true) {
                    PrimaryArray[SourceNode][Number[3]] = DistNode;
                    Number[3]++;
                }
                dualPass[3] = false;
            }
            if (SourceNode == 4) {
                for (int j = 0; j < PrimaryArray[DistNode].length; j++) {
                    if (PrimaryArray[DistNode][j] == SourceNode)
                        dualPass[4] = true;
                }
                if (dualPass[4] != true) {
                    PrimaryArray[SourceNode][Number[4]] = DistNode;
                    Number[4]++;
                }
                dualPass[4] = false;
            }
            if (SourceNode == 5) {
                for (int j = 0; j < PrimaryArray[DistNode].length; j++) {
                    if (PrimaryArray[DistNode][j] == SourceNode)
                        dualPass[5] = true;
                }
                if (dualPass[5] != true) {
                    PrimaryArray[SourceNode][Number[5]] = DistNode;
                    Number[5]++;
                }
                dualPass[5] = false;
            }
            if (SourceNode == 6) {
                for (int j = 0; j < PrimaryArray[DistNode].length; j++) {
                    if (PrimaryArray[DistNode][j] == SourceNode)
                        dualPass[6] = true;
                }
                if (dualPass[6] != true) {
                    PrimaryArray[SourceNode][Number[6]] = DistNode;
                    Number[6]++;
                }
                dualPass[6] = false;
            }
            if (SourceNode == 7) {
                for (int j = 0; j < PrimaryArray[DistNode].length; j++) {
                    if (PrimaryArray[DistNode][j] == SourceNode)
                        dualPass[7] = true;
                }
                if (dualPass[7] != true) {
                    PrimaryArray[SourceNode][Number[7]] = DistNode;
                    Number[7]++;
                }
                dualPass[7] = false;
            }
            if (SourceNode == 8) {
                for (int j = 0; j < PrimaryArray[DistNode].length; j++) {
                    if (PrimaryArray[DistNode][j] == SourceNode)
                        dualPass[8] = true;
                }
                if (dualPass[8] != true) {
                    PrimaryArray[SourceNode][Number[8]] = DistNode;
                    Number[8]++;
                }
                dualPass[8] = false;
            }
            if (SourceNode == 9) {
                for (int j = 0; j < PrimaryArray[DistNode].length; j++) {
                    if (PrimaryArray[DistNode][j] == SourceNode)
                        dualPass[9] = true;
                }
                if (dualPass[9] != true) {
                    PrimaryArray[SourceNode][Number[9]] = DistNode;
                    Number[9]++;
                }
                dualPass[9] = false;
            }
            if (SourceNode == 10) {
                for (int j = 0; j < PrimaryArray[DistNode].length; j++) {
                    if (PrimaryArray[DistNode][j] == SourceNode)
                        dualPass[10] = true;
                }
                if (dualPass[10] != true) {
                    PrimaryArray[SourceNode][Number[10]] = DistNode;
                    Number[10]++;
                }
                dualPass[10] = false;
            }

        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            System.out.println(PrimaryArray[i][1]);
        }
```

I have 2 problems:

1. about clean code that it is not and very long and has not readability. I want better solution.
2. about response that is false

for example when the input is :

```
3 14
1 2 
1 5 
1 9
1 3 
2 8 
2 6 
5 9 
9 4 
9 6 
3 10 
8 11 
7 11 
10 7 
6 7
```

output must be second member each. I want to say in this code that for example:

when we enter: 1 2
then 2 1
it must ignore 2 1.

output of code is wrong and I don't understand it.

Comment: 1. Start by following the naming convention. Variable names in java start with lowercase letter. Other than that, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the place for "how to make this code clearer", not StackOverflow. 2. I have no idea what you are asking in the second point, nor what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: *"output must be second member each"* - what? I'm very confused about the relationship between input/output here.

Answer (score 0):

For you first question, even if it's the wrong place there is an answer, just replace your

```
    // ...
    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
        int sourceNode = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("SourceNode: " + sourceNode);
        int distNode = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("DistNode: " + distNode );
        input.nextLine();
        // you will get same response with following code instead all your if's:
        for (int j = 0; j < primaryArray[distNode].length; j++) {
            if (primaryArray[distNode][j] == sourceNode)
                dualPass[sourceNode] = true;
        }
        if (dualPass[sourceNode] != true) {
            primaryArray[sourceNode][number[sourceNode]] = distNode;
            number[sourceNode]++;
        }
        dualPass[sourceNode] = false;
        // end of code change
    }
    // ...
```

Your second answer only can be answered if we get more informations, i do not have any Idea what your code should do yet.